# Driver-controlled mask modifier visibility / rendering causes pop effects

Tags: drivers

I am working on a stop motion style animation project.
To implement on / off toggles for facial expressions and hand-held props, we applied a driver controlled by a custom property to the mask modifier.
I finished rendering the keyframes for the animation and found that there were pops in some sections.
For example, facial expression A and B are displayed at the same time in the one frame where A changes to B, or a prop in the hand that was suddenly turned off in one frame appears and disappears.
All keyframes have hold interpolation.
Perhaps there is a problem with the driver update.

**Q: My rig needs visibility / rendering toggle for facial expression, props or costume.

Mask modifiers, however, cause pop effects.

Is this a bug or a known limitation?

What is the best way to do it?**

---

I followed Serge L's advice to check for errors in the system console and wrote the addition below.

Check the following error message.
[image]

I thought the mask modifier was the problem, but I was surprised to see the error related to binding.

I checked the character file and noticed that the eyes object has a modifier set up as shown in the image below.
[image]

But there is some doubt here.
The vertex count of the eyes object is not 6418.
I examined all the objects in my character but none of them had a 6418 vertex count.

I put the mask modifier on the eyes object last but I still see the same error on the system console.

**On the other hand, the biggest question is this.**
My rendering error occurred on a mouse object.
The mouse object was changing shape by a lip-sync animation, but when I checked the rendered PNG sequence, it was rendered with two mouths overlapping in a frame.
When I re-rendered the frame without modifying the blend file, it rendered correctly.
As such, the driver update missing I've been experiencing happens randomly.
The mouse object does not have an armature modifier and is just bone parented.
Can a vertex count mismatch of an unknown object with 6418 vertex counts miss a driver update for a mouse object that seems unrelated to it?

Comment: If you manually keyframe instead of driving, will it go smooth? Drivers are buggy if cycle dependency is present, open system console to to check for errors.

Comment: Yes. In my experience, keyframes were no problem.
The problem came from using the driver.
As your advice I have checked for cycle dependency errors in the system console.
I wrote an addition to the text, so please confirm it.

Comment: Bind errors usually come from modifiers utilizing binding such as Corrective Smooth, Surface/Mesh Deform, etc check if you have any. Also put a pic of driver's expression from graph editor.

Comment: @SergeL I'm sorry I came back late. The project has been completed and a new project has been started quickly. I want to study deeper into dependency errors, but I can't afford. In my next project, I will always keep an eye on the system console to manage the blend file so that there are no error messages, and I'll see if the mask modifier's visibility causes driver update errors even in clean blend files. Thanks for the hint.